# Using scopes and order with limit and offset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Working with postgresql and ruby on rails, I want to process a large database in batches. I cannot seem to use find_each as it works with the smallest id upwards. But I need to process the most recent data, which has the largest id.

My current attempt is

```
score_ok.order(cmp_id: :desc).limit(X).offset(Y).pluck(:id)
```

where score_ok is a scope with a where clause.
If I try this on a small test database, then with no limits and offset i.e

```
score_ok.order(cmp_id: :desc).pluck(:id)
```

I see

[372, 362, 363, 361, 366, 367, 368, 369, 370, 371, 364]

Now if I do

```
score_ok.order(cmp_id: :desc).limit(2).offset(0).pluck(:id)
```

I get

```
 [362, 361]
```

and if I do

```
score_ok.order(cmp_id: :desc).limit(2).offset(2).pluck(:id)
```

I get

```
[362, 366]
```

but what I want is [372, 362] and then [363, 361]. How do I do this? I have tried shifting the `limit(2).offset(2)` to the start of the query, but that does not help.

Comment: This ordering by `created_at` in the start is kinda misleading. Are you sure you are not using it instead of `comp_id`?

Comment: From the development logs, could you paste in the actual SQL that is being run? My guess is that the generated SQL is doing something unexpected and that will help you understand what's actually happening under the hood. When I face similar I usually end up using raw SQL.

Comment: potashin, I am using cmp_id (I have ediited the question) but if I replace with created_at, the query works as expected. cmp_id is of type date.   stef, I will have a look at the raw sql tomorrow.

Comment: `cmp_id` being a `date` (a type with limited granularity) and the behavior you're seeing (including the `created_at` behavior) suggest that you have duplicate `cmp_id` values. The database isn't required to sort equal values the same way every time, you may need to add a secondary sort key to break ties in a consistent fashion. Including more data (such as the `cmp_id` value for each `id`) would clear this up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mu is too short's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short) comment explained the behaviour. The cmp_id had duplicate values, and evidently the database is not required to sort equal values the same way each time.  One way to fix it is to add a secondary key to break ties in a consistent fashion.